# Packages with RcppArmadillo and c++11 do not export functions

Tags: r, c++11, rcpp

If I source the following code (the *.cpp file) everything is working and I can use the function in R:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>


// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec foo() {
 arma::vec x = { 1.1, 2.2 };
 return x;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int useAuto() {
  auto val = 42;
 return val;
}
```

However, if I use them in a package and built the package I get the following error messages if I try to use the functions in R:

```
Error in .Call(<pointer: (nil)>) : NULL value passed as symbol address**
```

It seems to be a problem with RcppArmadillo since it all workes well if I remove all RcppArmadillo features and use Rcpp only.

I included a src/Makevars.* with CXX_STD = CXX11 but that did not help with this issue.

Comment: I think you're trying to call `foo` from the Global environment, but it has disappeared because the installation restarted your session. Try `rm(foo)`.

Comment: I am afraid you need to show the package to us.

Comment: It was indeed a problem with the Global environment and the restart of the session. Thanks for the help.